# php button submit not work after use javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have problem with a button, it does not work on my second php page.

This is my first page, I choose a course then it will show the course details and test.

[print screen page 1 - tes.php](http://s17.postimg.org/4g22hkvsf/image.jpg)

at page 1 I use javascript to call `getuser.php`

```
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

On page 2 there is a radio button and a button, when I submit it will save data to database, but it does not work. But when I try a query ine test.php, it can save to database

[print screen page 2 - show getuser.php](http://s22.postimg.org/3rq362sjl/image.jpg)

```
    $q = $_GET['q'];

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE id_course='$q'");

echo "<table>
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id_course'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name_course'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


 echo "</table><br><table border='1'>";
echo "<form action='' method='post'> ";
        echo "   <tr><td>1+2 = </td>
                  <td><input type='radio' name='radio' value='1'>1</td>
                  <td><input type='radio' name='radio' value='2'>2</td>
                  <td><input type='radio' name='radio' value='3'>3</td>
                  <td><input type='radio' name='radio' value='4'>4</td>
                </tr>";         
        echo "</table><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'></form>";
?>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if (isset($_POST['radio']))
    {
        $ans=$_POST['radio'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO evaluation(
            id, id_course, total) VALUES (
            '1', '$q', '$ans')",$koneksi);
    }

}
?>
```

[file php and db](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-vErpEmJF3ULWlkV3M3WmFGWDA/view)

Comment: All your `<table>` html seems messed up. For instance, you have `echo "</table><br>";` but then right after that you have `echo " <tr>...` but no opening `<table>` tag.

Comment: thank you, I just edit...at first I use table to wrap form

Comment: It's not fixed. You removed the wrong part. This part `echo "</table><br>";
echo "<form action='' method='post'> ";
        echo " <tr>
          <td>`

Comment: You end the table but don't start a new one, you go right into `<tr>`

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, what does it do? Error?No error but no add to db? Form doesn't submit...?

Comment: no error but no add to db, when user select radio button and push button. I want add to db...but nothing happen to db.

Comment: Put `echo $ans;` after `if (isset($_POST['radio'])) {` see what it says.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `mysql_` anymore *(obligatory comment)*. It's deprecated/outdated and unsafe to use. You should be using the new `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared and bound variables/statements.

Comment: nothing happen. when I select and push button update it go directly to page 1.

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying now. I am following your logic. Probably the fastest fix is to put the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if (isset($_POST['radio']))
    {
        $ans=$_POST['radio'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO evaluation(
            id, id_course, total) VALUES (
            '1', '$q', '$ans')",$koneksi);
    }

}` on page 1 at the very top of the page before header (to keep your page tidy)

Comment: Your problem, at a glance, is that you're putting $q in quotes '$q' which makes it a string, not a variable.

Comment: @GaryHayes they are using POST and GET but not correctly.

Comment: Yeah I see that too, upon further inspection. Submitting the form via post and trying to pass the variable with get. So he's getting a blank variable and then turning it into a string. Double failure.

Comment: @GaryHayes Plus a direct $_GET variable right into an sql statement...triple failure. :(

Comment: @ Rasclatt but how I can get $q at page 1, because first I must select course to passing $q - id_course

Comment: Use a hidden field in your form to pass the $q variable with post.

Comment: In your form, do hidden values in your form `<input type="hidden" name="user" value="123" />`

Comment: Yes, very unsecure. It appears that he is learning though, so I won't pass too much judgement on the SQL injections. Let him get the basics down first, then learn how to secure the inputs.

Comment: yes I am still learning...thank you for your help  Gary Hayes and Rasclatt .. I will try...